# UIViewAnimationOption Enum Cover Vertical

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to push a ViewController with a custom modal animation.  I would prefer to use the "Cover Vertical" animation.  Is there a `UIViewAnimationOption` for "Cover Vertical"?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:nil completion:nil];
```

Replace `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` with ... ?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Animation Controller.  The code to set this up looks like this:

```
- (id)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController (UIViewController *)source
{
    return self.animationController;
}

- (id )animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
     self.animationController.isPresenting = NO;

    return self.animationController;
}
```

Then you need to use the following method determine if you are presenting or dismissing:

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id)transitionContext{

if(self.isPresenting){
    [self executePresentationAnimation:transitionContext];
}
else{
    [self executeDismissalAnimation:transitionContext];
}

}
```

Finally, you define your animations, the following code will push the view in from the top as modal view:

```
-(void)executePresentationAnimation:(id)transitionContext{

UIView* inView = [transitionContext containerView];

UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

[inView addSubview:toViewController.view];

CGPoint centerOffScreen = inView.center;

centerOffScreen.y = (-1)*inView.frame.size.height;
toViewController.view.center = centerOffScreen;

[UIView animateWithDuration:self.presentationDuration delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.4f initialSpringVelocity:6.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

    toViewController.view.center = inView.center;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}];
}
```

and when you dismiss the reverse should happen:

```
-(void)executeDismissalAnimation:(id)transitionContext{

UIView* inView = [transitionContext containerView];

UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

[inView insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

CGPoint centerOffScreen = inView.center;
centerOffScreen.y = (-1)*inView.frame.size.height;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:self.dismissalDuration delay:0.0f options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        CGPoint center = fromViewController.view.center;
        center.y += 50;
        fromViewController.view.center = center;
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        fromViewController.view.center = centerOffScreen;

    }];


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}];
}
```